# Could not find the created file by keytool genkeypair

Tags: java, keytool

I just ran the command

```
keytool -genkeypair
```

but do not find the created `JKS` file.

Comment: Have you considered consulting the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is not specified the default location is

```
${USER_HOME}/.keystore
```

(both on Windows and Linux systems)

Otherwise, you have the option to specify the file explicitly

```
keytool -genkeypair -keystore mykey.jks
```

which creates the `mykey.jks` in the active directory